# On equality involving continuous functions and boundary sets

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove a fact related to projections on $\mathbb{R}^\infty. $ Specifically, assume that $\pi_K: \mathbb{R}^\infty \mapsto \mathbb{R}^K $ where, say, $K = \{1, 2, \ldots, k\} $ for any integer $k. $ 
Let's assume that $H \in {\cal B}(\mathbb{R}^K), $ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^K. $ 
I would like to show, if true, that 
$$\partial (\pi_K^{-1}H) = \pi_K^{-1}\partial H, $$
with $\partial $ denoting the boundary set. I know that projections are continuous functions and I suspect that is what should help. Howeer, I would have expected this fact to be trivial, instead it is more difficult than I envisioned it.

I tried to limit myself to projections from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ to $\mathbb{R} $ and when I try to prove the two inclusions required for the equality of the two sets, I am not even too sure it is true in general.

I would appreciate if anyone could provide some guidance. Thank you.

Maurice

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody seemed to care much about this question, I tried to solve it on my own and propose it here in case someone cares to take a look at what I have done. It seems to "fly", but one never knows...

Assume that $x \in proj_K^{-1}(\partial H) $ which implies that $proj_K x \in \partial H. $ Hence there are points $\alpha^u \in H $ with $\alpha^u = (\alpha_1^u, \ldots, \alpha_k^u, x_{k+1}, \ldots) $ and $\beta_u \in H^c $ with $\beta^u= (\beta_1^u, \ldots, \beta_k^u, x_{k+1}, \ldots) $ such that $\alpha^u \to proj_Kx $ and
$\beta^u \to proj_Kx $ as $u \to \infty. $ Since the points $\alpha^u $ lie in $proj_K^{-1}H $
and converge to $x, $ and since the points $\beta^u $ lie in $(proj_K^{-1}H)^c $ and converge to $x, $ then we must have that $x \in \partial(proj_K^{-1} H) $ which shows that
$proj_K^{-1}(\partial H) \subset \partial (proj_K^{-1}H). $

Assume now that $x \in \partial (proj_K^{-1}H). $ Then there must exist points $\alpha^u \in proj_K^{-1}H $ with $\alpha^u = (\alpha_1^u, \ldots, \alpha_k^u, x_{k+1}, \ldots) $ and $\beta_u \in (proj_K^{-1}H)^c=proj_K^{-1}H^c $ with $\beta^u= (\beta_1^u, \ldots, \beta_k^u, x_{k+1}, \ldots) $ such that $\alpha^u \to x $ and
$\beta^u \to x $ as $u \to \infty. $ Now, since projections are continuous functions,
$proj_K\alpha^u \in H, $ $proj_K \beta^u \in H^c, $ and $proj_K \alpha^u \to proj_Kx, $
$proj_K \beta^u \to proj_Kx $ as $u \to \infty. $ This
implies that $proj_Kx \in \partial H $ and $x \in proj_K^{-1}(\partial H). $  This shows that $\partial (proj_K^{-1}H) \subset proj_K^{-1}(\partial H) $ which completes the proof of the statement.